# get_the_terms does not return cat_id

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy

i am usign this code to get the cat_id

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $id,'category' );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    $cats[] = $term->cat_ID;
}
```

However when i do 
    print_r($terms);

This is what i get

```
Array
(
    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 10
            [name] => Technology
            [slug] => technology
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 10
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [object_id] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

As you can see the cat_ID is not included and there is [filter] => raw. What is the [filter] => raw ?
Note: I am using wordpress 4.0
Thank you,
MMK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`term_id` is same as `cat_ID`. `filter` contains the context under which the contents of the post have been filtered.

`raw` => unsanitized data

[Read here about `filter`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29847/whats-object-filter-for)

Comment: Is there any way of getting cat_ID using the same code?

Comment: `term_id` is `cat_ID`. Use `term_id`.